# How to pop up the python console?

Tags: python, console, popup

well what i am trying to do is, I'm building a small compiler only for arithmetic evaluation using python! String of any length should be accepted and also, i need to pop up a console where the user can enter his query! 
Can anyone help me out with the popup of the console?

Comment: I suppose you could use a `Tkinter.Textbox` or something.

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you can describe your problem in more detail. For instance, is your application also in python? Is it a GUI application? If so, what GUI toolkit are you currently using?

Comment: opps! I'm sorry.. I'll keep things in mind the next time i post something :) 
And as far as my question is considered, i want to try using the python code itself by not using any GUI toolss.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.system("python")
```

will open a new python window ...

```
raw_input("Enter Equation:")
```

would just get a single equation from the user

not sure if either of those is what you are looking for ...

```
import wx
a = wx.App()
user_string = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter Equation:")
```

would pop up a prompt for user input (as long as you have wx installed)